# Linear ODE with non-constant coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have encountered some problem in computing the explicit solution for the following ODE:

$$x^\prime(t) = (2t-1) x(t)-1, \quad x(0) =: x_{0}$$

The formula that I have used to solve it is:

$$\Large{\left[k-\int^{t}b(s)e^{\int^{s}a(u)du}ds\right]e^{\int^{t}a(s)ds}}$$

with $a=(2t-1)$ and $b=-1$.

Am I using the correct formula?

Thanks

Comment: i don't know which formula do you use

Comment: Do you mean $a(s)$ in the last integral, not $e(s)$? Anyway, rather than learning the formula, why not learn the *method*, which is called the method of integrating factors for first order linear ODEs.

Comment: Yes, Ian, you're right, it is $a(s) in the last integral. My fault. The formula comes from the Simon-Blume Mathematics for economist book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a 1st order linear ODE with varying coefficients

$$\dot{x} = (2t-1) \, x - 1$$

where the initial condition is $x_0$. The homogeneous solution is

$$x_h (t) = x_0 \, \exp\left(\displaystyle\int (2 t - 1) \, \mathrm{d}t\right) = x_0 \, \exp\left(t^2 - t\right)$$

Hence, we try a solution of the form

$$x (t) = \kappa (t) \, \exp\left(t^2 - t\right)$$

which yields a 1st order ODE in $\kappa$

$$\dot{\kappa} (t) = - \exp\left(-t^2 + t\right)$$

Integrating,

$$\kappa (t) = \kappa_0 - \displaystyle\int_0^t \exp\left(-\tau^2 + \tau\right) \, \mathrm{d} \tau$$

Hence, the solution to the given ODE is

$$x (t) = \left(x_0 - \displaystyle\int_0^t \exp\left(-\tau^2 + \tau\right) \, \mathrm{d} \tau\right) \exp\left(t^2 - t\right)$$

Note that the integrand above is a Gaussian function, which isn't integrable.